# Apple Login Using ColdFusion and Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]I have problem with Apple login not properly handle call back function getting from Apple Website.
Can any one help me how i handle the call back link

[image]

Thanks
Now i have this message..
[image]

Comment: **Edit**: Thanks for the update, but please post code as text to help the next person with the same problem.  (Images aren't searchable). (Also, it doesn't look like this is related to "ColdFusion". You might update the question tags and/or add a few tags, so the question reaches more people).

Comment: The error message plainly states you can't use `await` in your JavaScript function the way you have. This has nothing to do with ColdFusion.